# Filter function by category and company using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this code here that allows me to filter my products by category ($scope.myFilter). This works fine, but I want to as well add the functionality to filter products by company, but it seems that I can't do it without a bit of help.

```
app.controller('AdminController_Music', function ($scope, $filter) {

var myStore = new store();
$scope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 12;
$scope.numberOfPages = Math.ceil(myStore.products_sound.length / $scope.pageSize);

$scope.filteredItems = [];
$scope.groupedItems = [];
$scope.pagedItems = [];

var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
    if (!needle) {
        return true;
    }
    return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
};
$scope.search = function (name) {
    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(myStore.products_sound, function (product) {
        for (var attr in product) {
            if (searchMatch(product[name], $scope.query))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.groupToPages();
};
$scope.myFilter = function (column, category) {
    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(myStore.products_sound, function (product) {
        for (var attr in product) {
            if (searchMatch(product[column], category))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.groupToPages();
};
$scope.groupToPages = function () {
    $scope.pagedItems = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
        if (i % $scope.pageSize === 0) {
            $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.pageSize)] = [$scope.filteredItems[i]];
        } else {
            $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.pageSize)].push($scope.filteredItems[i]);
        }
    }
};
// functions have been describe process the data for display
$scope.myFilter();
$scope.search();

});
```

I tried playing with the myFilter function but with not good results.

```
    this.products_sound = [
      { num: 1, code: '001s', category: 'toy', company:'lego', name: 'lego1', src: "product/1.jpg", description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. ', price: 69.99, class: 'show-down' },
```

This is the HTML. The second li works and the first not...

```
<ul class="filter group albumFilter">
                    <p>Brands:</p>
                    <li ng-click="myFilter('company','lego'" >Lego</li>
                    <li ng-click="myFilter('category','construction')" >Construct</li>
                </ul>
```

Here is the production version of the code. It is in [Cyrillic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cyrillic), so don't bother with the text. Just navigate down to the product loop; the sorting buttons are on top of that:

http://konstantindichev.com/flexfit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your filter doesn't work correctly. It can be done much easier:

```
$scope.myFilter = function(key, value) {
    var search = {};
    search[key] = value;

    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(myStore.products_sound, search);
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.groupToPages();
};
```

You can filter your items by an object (e.g. `$filter('filter')(myStore.products_sound,{company: "lego"});`

You can see some examples here: http://voryx.net/using-angularjs-filter-inside-the-controller/

Comment: Hey thanks I will try this tomorrow morning and check this answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed my function to work properly as intended by changing the way it looks for the sorted items.

```
    $scope.myFilter = function (attribute, string) {
    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(myStore.products_sound, function (product) {
        for (var attr in product) {
            if (searchMatch(product[attribute], string))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.groupToPages();
    };
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `searchMatch` function? Angular provides the same functionality out of the box.